# upstart: how to capture events emitted during boot process

Tags: logging

using upstart for my device and I want to monitor the boot process by listening all the events (log or send it to another pc). Also i want to add time stamp information to the emitted event.

From cookbook, i am trying to record the events as follows but still it doesnt work.
Note:using 0.3.11 version of upstart.

start on (startup \
or starting \
or started \
or stopping )

script
exec 1>>/tmp/test.log
echo "Job=$UPSTART_JOB process:$UPSTART_JOB_PROCESS"
end script

Issue is 1)when i have combined events like above for start on, my script doesnt seems to be running at all,, where as if i keep only one event e.g start on starting, it seems to be recording the event, is there anything wrong in the syntax, does it work this way in 0.3.11 version of upstart?

2)how do I record the job which gets executed when certain event was emitted with time stamp?

Comment: The Ubuntu project provides a lot of documentation for Upstart. Check out the [Upstart Cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/). It thoroughly covers everything Upstart.

Comment: well, i read this in upstart cookbook under section 11.51   Record all Jobs and Events which Emit an Event but i dnt get the list of events emitted by the each job during bootup process. it only gives info about my test.conf and doesnt list like (initctl list).